# In which areas do I have to be to get choppers delivered to specific airfields?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

When I buy a chopper in GTA 5 online, I can call Pegasus to get those choppers delivered to an airport or helipad.

Unfortunately, if I get myself next to an airport and call Pegasus, the chopper isn't delivered to the current airport I'm at, but to another one on the map. But they aren't delivered to airports randomly, it seems that each airport corresponds to a specific area where you have to be when you make that call.

Does anyone know these areas (best would be a map with those areas indicated)? Or do you know better and can tell the mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

They're delivered to the nearest helipad, in a straight line, from where you are.  The only exception to this is when you're too close.  For example, a helicopter will spawn at the helipad in Vespucci if you are at the subway station (overground) across the road, but any closer than that and it will spawn at the hospital.

The more you call them the more you'll get used to it.  Generally, if you can see the helipad then it won't spawn there.